# ¿Cúal de los siguientes términos para la nevera es el más común?

Tags: vocabulario, españa

Mi diccionario de español da los siguientes términos como sinónimos.

- la nevera
- el refrigerador
- el frigorífico

¿Cuál de estos términos es el más común en España?

Comment: ¿Quieres referirte al electrodoméstico, lo que en inglés sería «refridgerator»?  Y en tal caso, al conjunto entero con el congelador o solo a la parte que mantiene las cosas frías sin congelar?  Porque estos términos tienen una variedad de significados y no son sinónimos absolutos.

Comment: Mi diccionario dice que todas estas palabras son los sinónimos de "fridge" de ingleso. Me qustaría saber cúal es el término más popular en España.

Comment: Quería dar una respuesta pero tendré que abstenerme dado que no soy español. Sin embargo, creo que el uso es regional. Se usa bastante *refrigerador* y también *nevera*.

Comment: @Subjunctive Yo soy español y vivo en España y la palabra *refrigerador* apenas la escucho; justo lo contrario de *nevera* y *frigorífico*.

Comment: @Jdamian Interesante. Yo soy chileno y *refri* o *refrigerador* se usan siempre.

Comment: En Puerto Rico solo se usa la palabra nevera, no sabía que también se usaba en España.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En España, una **nevera** puede ser tanto la parte que mantiene los productos fríos sin congelarlos como el conjunto entero. Un **congelador** es la parte que, como su nombre lo indica, congela. Un **frigorífico** puede significar tanto la parte que congela, la parte que sólo mantiene los productos fríos o el conjunto entero.

Popularmente, se usa *nevera* para la parte que enfría sin congelar y *congelador* para la parte que congela. Técnicamente, se suele usar *frigorífico* para la parte que enfría sin congelar y *congelador* para la parte que congela. Como muestra, transcribo la etiqueta de un paquete de guisantes de mi casa comprado en el Mercadona:

> CONSERVACIÓN
>
> Frigorífico (+7°) — 1 día
>
> Congelador o cajón para hielo (-6°) — 1 semana
>
> Congelador o cajón ultracongelador (-18°) — consumir preferentemente antes de: ver envase

Por otra parte, en los centros comerciales que venden electrodomésticos, a la sección de neveras la llaman "sección de frigoríficos". No es que vendan sólo frigoríficos (sin congeladores), sino que como el frigorífico es la parte más grande de una nevera, se llama así al conjunto entero por metonimia.

**Refrigerador** no es tan común en España (o al menos en el centro) como lo es congelador, aunque tampoco es raro oírlo.

En resumen, la palabra más común es ***nevera***.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia mucho según la región.

En España refrigerador no se usa casi nunca, mientras que en Latinoamérica es más frecuente.

Dentro de España, depende de la región o incluso la familia. En mi casa siempre se ha dicho frigorífico o, más comunmente, frigo. Pero tengo vecinos que dicen siempre nevera.